# Using Tidyr Extract and Regex to Clean Up a Messy Dataframe Column containing Wages and Salaries

Tags: regex, r, tidyr

Struggling a bit with a regular expression. I'm new to regex, and I created a basic example data frame below. I'm attempting to use `tidyr`'s extract function to extract hourly pay from `Hourly.Pay` into a new column called `Hourly`.

```
Name <- c("Client1","Client2","Client3","Client4","Client5","Client6","Client7","Client8","Client9","Client10","Client11","Client12","Client13")

Hourly.Pay <- c("$14.00","$14","$20.22","$18.00/Hour","$15","19/hourly","$40,000","$345.00","$1920/month","$11.25","12.75 hr","67K/year","15.25")

Pay<-data.frame(Name,Hourly.Pay)
```

Below is what I have so far for the regex, which almost works. I haven't been able to capture entries that don't have a period after the first two digits. I need to capture an optional dollar sign, and then two digits that are either followed by a period, a period and at least two more digits, or no period or any other digits.

```
Pay2 <- extract(Pay, Hourly.Pay, "Hourly", "^(\\$?\\d{2}\\.\\d*)",remove=FALSE)
```

Help would be appreciated. If possible, it would be great if an explanation is provided as well for the regex characters.

Thanks!

Comment: Works (for the sample data, at least), but is almost as ugly as the data: `extract(Pay, Hourly.Pay, 'Hourly', '(?<![,\\.\\d])(\\$?\\d{2}(?:\\.\\d*)?)(?![Kk,\\.\\d])', FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks. What does the (?<! mean? I haven't seen that before. Same with the :

Comment: `(?<! ... )` is [a negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (the characters inside are not before what follows), and `(?: ... )` is [a non-caputuring group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). See [an explanation of the matching here](https://regex101.com/r/dK3uO5/1).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer. I took the liberty to clean up your data. It is ridiculously messy and you need better data management.

```
library(rex)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

scale = data_frame(scale = c("K", ""),
                   scale_value = c(1000, 1) )

time_unit = data_frame(time_unit = c("", "hr", "hour", "hourly", "month", "year"),
                       time_value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 40/7*30, 40/7*30*12) )

interpretation = 
  rex("$" %>% maybe,
      some_of(number, ".", ",") %>% capture,
      "K" %>% maybe %>% capture,
      one_of(" ", "/") %>% maybe,
      letters %>% maybe %>% capture )

result = 
  Pay %>%
  extract(Hourly.Pay, 
          c("wage_raw", "scale", "time_unit_raw"), 
          interpretation) %>%
  mutate(wage = wage_raw %>% extract_numeric,
         time_unit = 
           (wage > 10000) %>%
           ifelse("year", time_unit_raw) %>%
           stri_trans_tolower) %>%
  left_join(scale) %>%
  left_join(time_unit) %>%
  mutate(estimated_wage = wage * scale_value / time_value)
```